# Spring MVC, Serving RESTFul request (json) and JSP (content negotiation)

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, content-negotiation

I'm trying to create a Spring MVC 4 web project (Maven project) in order to handle REST requests. 
The system should answer with a web page in case the HTTP accept is text/html
and in json in case it is application/json (and possibly other formats like XML in case it is application/xml).

I've set up a controller and the JSP (I've also used the @RestController). The problem is that I cannot make it working togheter. If the system is correctly answer with a JSP, then the json service is not working and vice versa.
Do I have to set an handler for each representation, and how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you try to handle REST requests or just try to make an ajax request ? you can create specific controller with methods that return jsp and some methods annotated by @ResponseBody that return JSON or XML content

Comment: I would like to have one rest request (like example.com/get/resourceID) and get as a response different formats (web jsp, json xml ...). How can i set different handler based on the content negotiation?

Answer (score 1):

To determining what format the user has requested relies on a **ContentNegotationStrategy**,there are default implementations available out of the box,but you can also implement your own if you wish

To configure and use content negotiation with Spring using **HTTP message converters** :

You have to enable Content Negotiation in Spring MVC :

```
<bean id="cnManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>

    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Or using java configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


  @Override
 public void configureContentNegotiation(
            ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true).
            ignoreAcceptHeader(true).
            useJaf(false).
            defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).
            mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML).
            mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
            mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already testedt this, using the @RestController annotation but when you call the resource with the application/json header it returns the json; when you call with a standard text/html header it cannot find the viewer even if the JSP is there. Do I have to create a specific handler?

Comment: This is normal the jsp page are resolved by ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"   you have to sperate your rest service ! from your methods that should return views !

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I added an example :your pages should be in this folder /WEB-INF/views/ if you're working with spring boot you have to create one an change the type of package from jar to war

Answer (score 0):

This is an exemple : 
the first method will return client.jsp page for each get for url end .../client and the second will return a client json object for each get end .../clients/id

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/client", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getClientPage(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final Model model,final HttpSession session) {
      // traitement 

    return new ModelAndView("client");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/clients/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Client getClient(@pathVariable("id") long id) {

    Client client =  YourService.getClient(id);

    return client;
}
```

Contentnegotiatingviewresolver java config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.yourbasepackage")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, but I am already at that point... the problem is that my application should answer with different formats, to the same URL based on the HTTP accept header. Example -> URL: /clients/123 Accept: text/html returns the JSP; URL: /clients/123 Accept: application/json returns the json